# Log4j2 not creating log file with Spring Boot in Linux

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am using Log4j2 for logging with Spring Boot , but it is not creating the log file. Given below is my configuration for Log4j2 and dependencies i added.

**Log4j2 configuration** -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        </Console>
        
        <!-- File Appender -->
        <File name="File" fileName=".logs/app.log">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
 
    <Loggers>
        <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
 
        <!-- LOG "com.baeldung*" at TRACE level -->
        <Logger name="com.ams" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
 
</Configuration>
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Is there any other configuration or dependency i need to add ? Because according to the blogs on web **log4j2** should create the log file with the configuration provided above.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) link will help you.
In my case i had to exclude the spring boot startet logging in the pom xml because otherwise the default logging logback is active and log4j won't be used.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably, this is late, but still would like to answer the question anyway. I added the spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency to the pom and excluded the spring-boot-starter-logging dependency. Also, credit goes to @medTech for his answer as it made me try a different variation of his solution. 
Please note I am using **spring boot 2.2.6.RELEASE**, this is **not tested with 1.x version**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```